# Powershell Get-ADUser calculated property Select-Object : Cannot convert System.String[]?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

This one below works fine with no issue:

```
$properties = 'Name,msExchRemoteRecipientType,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,proxyAddresses' -split ','
Get-ADUser -identity 'Lee.Xia' -Properties $properties |
Select-Object $properties
```

But this one below which formats the Email Addresses only with SMTP not working?
adding this line: `@{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }}`

so it will be like:

```
$properties = 'Name,msExchRemoteRecipientType,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,proxyAddresses' -split ','
Get-ADUser -identity 'Lee.Xia' -Properties $properties |
Select-Object $properties, @{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }}
```

This is the error code:

```
Select-Object : Cannot convert System.String[] to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:3 char:1
+ Select-Object $properties, @{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Property` parameter of `Select-Object` expects a single property or an array of properties. Since `$properties` is already an array, you need to add your calculated property to it using `+` rather than `,`.

```
$properties = 'Name,msExchRemoteRecipientType,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,proxyAddresses' -split ','
Get-ADUser -identity 'Lee.Xia' -Properties $properties |
Select-Object ($properties + @{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }})
```

Using `,` instead of `+` creates an array of two elements. The first element is your array of `$properties`. The second element is the calculated property. `Select-Object` is not going to unroll that as a single array.